# Executing Jenkins email-ext plugin not as last post-build action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I am using the email-ext plugin v.2.38.1 (post-build action "Editable Email Notification") on Jenkins v.1.566 to send e-mails after the build when certain conditions are met.

When using multiple post-build actions, I got the impression that the email-ext plugin always comes last and is executed after all other actions, no matter how I put the order of actions in the configuration. Other plugins respect the order and are executed accordingly [as described in this issue.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7408)

Is there any possibility to execute another post-build action after sending the e-mails? In my case, I would like to run a shell script doing some clean-up in the workspace which cannot run before because it will delete a file that is part of the e-mail body.

One could work around this by defining an extra clean-up job which is triggered after the main job is completed, however, I would prefer having everything defined in one job only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emailing is a publishing action which occures always after build and post build actions ..

Additionally I think you should clean something before running the job (at startup eventually) but never at the end.

How can you study your issues if you destroy all materials that should enable you to do so ?

Comment: Okay, that's a point. Regarding your question: My jobs download and test some files. In case that everything goes well, data and results should just be removed from the workspace - else, data and results are copied from the workspace to a shared network location for further inspection before cleaning up the workspace. Cleaning up before the job runs would probably be possible, I already thought about that. However, multiple jobs producing similar files and results share this workspace which made it a little bit more difficult.

Comment: You should use the DeployArtifact  in build step and clean partially your workspace .... partially means decide what to keep for beeing able to write the mail .. It is an idea to be able to clean the deployed matter after transfert. I will add a requirement to do so in the deployArtifact in future version

Answer (score 1):

The step `Editable Email Notification` is always executed at last in the post-build actions, but you can use a `Editable Email Notification Templates` step which can be executed in the order you specified in post-build actions